# Bugfix for BorderWidth > 0 in combination with a scroll bar?

Tags: delphi, scrollbar

During writing a custom control, while trying to implement the default `BorderWidth` property correctly, I seem to have stumbled upon a bug in the painting behaviour when scroll bars are shown: the spaces between the scroll bars and the control's extent are not painted.

To reproduce the bug, implement the following `OnCreate` handler for the main form of a new project:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AutoScroll := True;
  BorderWidth := 20;
  SetBounds(10, 10, 200, 200);
  with TGroupBox.Create(Self) do
  begin
    SetBounds(300, 300, 50, 50);
    Parent := Self;
  end;
end;
```

The results for D7 and XE2:

[image]

It seems that this is fixed at last in Delphi XE2. Likely, this bug would reside in `TWinControl.WMNCPaint`, but looking at `Controls.pas`, I cannot find any significant differences in the implementation between D7 and XE2.

I would like to get answers on:

- How to write a bugfix for this oddity,
- From which Delphi version this bug seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### From which Delphi version fixed?

The [search results](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?search=1&type=B+OR+A+OR+D+OR+C&proj=10&kw=borderwidth) in QualityCentral on *BorderWidth* shows that this bug is not reported before. Bug [QC 2433](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=2433) (which was resolved in D2010, update 4) seems related, but from the comments I understand the bug in question does not exist in D2007.

Verification from the community here is more needed though.

#### How to fix for versions < D2007?

Override the `WM_NCPAINT` message handler:

```
  private
    procedure WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint); message WM_NCPAINT;

procedure TForm1.WMNCPaint(var Message: TWMNCPaint);
{$IF CompilerVersion < 19}
var
  DC: HDC;
  WindowStyle: Longint;
  TotalBorderWidth: Integer;
{$IFEND}
begin
{$IF CompilerVersion < 19}
  DC := GetWindowDC(Handle);
  try
    WindowStyle := GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE);
    if WindowStyle and WS_VSCROLL <> 0 then
      TotalBorderWidth := (Width - ClientWidth - GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL)) div 2
    else
      TotalBorderWidth := (Width - ClientWidth) div 2;
    if WindowStyle and WS_HSCROLL <> 0 then
      FillRect(DC, Rect(0, Height - TotalBorderWidth, Width, Height), Brush.Handle);
    if WindowStyle and WS_VSCROLL <> 0 then
      FillRect(DC, Rect(Width - TotalBorderWidth, 0, Width, Height), Brush.Handle);
  finally
    ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
  end;
{$IFEND}
  inherited;
end;
```

The two drawn rects are intentionally too large, giving better results at resizing.

Comment: Not able to duplicate with D2007.

Comment: @Ser But you dó have the bug from [QC 2433](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=2433)?

Comment: I'm not sure. When I set the color before the form is shown, then there's no problem. If I change it at runtime, borders do not comply with the new color. Resizing, as told in the report, causes the borders to be painted with the correct color.

Comment: @Ser That's the bug. Well, then this from OP is another one.

Comment: @NGLN - I disagree, the report has no mention of changing the color after the form is shown. But I'd easily agree that they're connected..

Comment: Same bug with D5. But no `Self.TotalBorderWidth` there.

Comment: @kobik Ah tanks, that was sloppy of me. Fixed.

Comment: @NGLN, Cool, but I would call `GetWindowLong` only one time.

Comment: Can use `[Horz|Vert]ScrollbarVisible` instead of style checking?

Comment: @Ser `TControlScrollBar.IsScrollBarVisible` does the same. But I didn't use that because this fix shouldn't only work for `TScrollingWinControl` descendants, but for every `TWinControl` descendant.

Comment: @kobik Yes, that's better. Done.