# Make a borderless resizable window in WinAPI

Tags: c, winapi, tdm-gcc

I wanna make a borderless resizable window in c language using TDM-GCC compilers.

I use  built-in TDM-GCC library and CreateWindowEX(...) function to make a window.

I know that I can use `WS_POPUP | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX` to make titleless resizable window; but I wanna make borderless window exactly with no border.

Thank you.

Comment: How is the user going to resize the window if there is no border to grab? `WS_SIZEBOX` [is a synonym of](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) `WS_THICKFRAME`. I think what you want can't be done just be means of setting window styles.

Comment: I mean transparent or invisible border.
Like electron frameless window.

Comment: Respond to `WM_NCHITTEST` with one of the resizing constants when the mouse is over the appropriate part of your window.

Comment: I noticed that Jonathan pointed out that the method can solve this problem. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639341/how-to-get-a-windows-10-style-transparent-border). Although it is delphi, the calling method is similar.