# Searching for custom thumbnail viewer component with dynamic layout

Tags: delphi, layout, grid, thumbnails

I need a control which can display thumbnails similar as seen on the attached image.

It should support:

- virtual mode
- handle up to 50.000 images
- thumbnail groups
- scaling
- work with Delphi XE3.

If such control does not yet exist I would have to create one from scratch. What is the best strategy for developing a control like this?

[See an example of what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owiv1.png)

Comment: If you're up to the challenge, you can play around with a TScrollBox and it's OnPaint event, you pre-load X images before the "actual view" and X after it, when scrolling, you simply paint the images.

Comment: See my [ImageGrid component](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8954813/757830).

Answer (score 2):

RMKlever has a series of blog-posts and sample code [here.](http://rmklever.com/?tag=thumbnails) that can emulate a wide variety of things, but you would have to make code modifications yourself if you're particular about your desired format.

I believe the control is one of his own called [rkView](http://rmklever.com/?tag=rkview). The demos may require a lot of work to get them working for you, I found working with his stuff was difficult to get started with due to lack of documentation and samples but I eventually figured it all out.