# Display all images in a folder using a list view item in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am using RAD Studio xe6 and I have a simple Firemonkey form, what I want to do is get all Images that are in a folder and display them in a list for the user to see, is this possible, and if yes how.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What you need to do is show us what you have tried so far and what is not working.

Comment: See [AwImageGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8954813/757830). But conversion to a FM component probably will need some work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delphi already ships with a sample program which does similar thing that you seek. The sample program is called FireFlow. If you haven't installed sample programs while installing Delphi you can get the sample program from:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE6/en/FMX.FireFlow_Sample

But othervise what you want to do is first search the specific directory for supported image files. To do this use FindFirst, FindNext.

Then you need to decide how are you going to display these images. Now if you intend to display them inside the listbox controll do check the CustomListBox sample which you can also get from web here:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE6/en/FMX.CustomListBox_Sample

Comment: +1 SilverWarrior! Do you know if the FireFlow example reads the EXIF thumbnail from an image or does it render from the image's pixeldata? It would be a major performance enhancement if the thumbnail is read...

Comment: That I'm not sure. I'm not on development machine right now so I can't check it out.

Comment: Anywhay if that is not supported you can find an exampple program intended to read the data from thumbnail.db here: http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojectreleases/thumbsdbviewer I gues that with some work that could be implemented in your application.