# Sorting TSTringList Names property as integers instead of strings

Tags: delphi

I have a  large file of text data where each line looks like such

```
10005=08/18/09,No BS,25094,wrg1
```

and the data is out of order (i.e. the number before the equal sign)

I load this file into a StringList as Name Value pairs. The TStringList sort function does not of course because the numbers are strings and not integers.

How can i get these into order before loading them into the TStringList?

Is there a fast function that I perform the file on that returns a TStrings that I can assign to the TStringList?

thankx

Comment: Why do you need this in the described order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function StrCmpLogicalW(sz1, sz2: PWideChar): Integer; stdcall;
  external 'shlwapi.dll' name 'StrCmpLogicalW';

function MyCompare(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := StrCmpLogicalW(PWideChar(List[Index1]), PWideChar(List[Index2]));
end;
```

Usage:

```
  StringList.CustomSort(MyCompare);
```

Comment: @TLama No need to declare as `PWideChar`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10437339/757830).

Comment: I know that it's not required (hence the edit comment). The best I would use is `PCWSTR` if it were defined in Delphi.